# Why does my profile show twice on the Winter Bash leaderboard?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, winterbash-leaderboard

In the Windows Phone leaderboard, it shows my profile twice. This shouldn't happen.

[image: preview]

Here's the link: [Windows Phone Leaderboard - Winter Bash](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/windowsphone.stackexchange.com)

Comment: An alternate design could have been made, looks twice on the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The first entry is highlighted now, separating your standing from the list that follows:

[image: Rankings List]

Previously it looked like this:

[image: Former Rankings List]

Answer (score 7):

Because you're shown at the top of the list, and then again where you actually are in the list.

So if you're top dog, you're listed twice.

So for me, I see this:

[image]

And if I scroll down far enough, I'll see my own avatar at spot #40.

And now I'm #1 on Windows Phone (sorry):
[image]